# Is it possible to have conditional property in ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I understand there is option to have conditional output for property values, but is it possible to have conditional property itself. For example I have template which creates `Microsoft.Compute/VirtualMachine` and it's the same template for both Windows and Linux. But for windows I need to specify property which do not exist for Linux (`"licenseType": "Windows_Server")`. Presense of this property will fail deployment with error `The property 'LicenseType' cannot be used together with property 'linuxConfiguration'`

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to have this property included only for Windows images while keeping template the same?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

yes it is possible, but hacky. several options:

1. create 2 VM resources with different properties, condition them so that only one gets deployed
2. use union function and variables to construct resulting object
3. append property as a separate deployment (might not work with all the cases)

let me expand number two a bit:

```
"variables": {
    "baseObject": {
        "propertyOne": "xxx",
        "propertyTwo": "yyy"
    },
    "additionalObject": {
        "optionalProperty": "zzz"
    }
}
```

and then in your object you can do:

```
"property": "[if(something, variables('baseObject'), # new line for readability
    union(variables('baseObject'), variables('additionalObject') ))]"
```

Comment: This requires all properties of VirtualMachine to be defined as `variable` to work, right?

Comment: not necessary, you can apply this at any level, you just cant make half the object defined and half calculated

Comment: `licenseType` property top level property for VirtualMachine, so for this approach to work I need to put the rest of the properties to be calculated too?

Comment: if it is directly under properties, yes. one thing you can try is doing: `"licenseType": "[json('null')]"`

Comment: Take a look at: https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-vm-custom-script-output/nestedtemplates/vm.json#L166

Answer (score 14):

Here is what I end up doing based on a previous answer as well as comments

1. Define variable is you are dealing with Windows

`"isWindowsOS": "[equals(parameters('ImageReferenceOffer'), 'WindowsServer')]"`

2. In properties for VM resource use it as below. No need for nested deployments etc. 
     
      `"properties": {
      "licenseType": "[if(variables('isWindowsOS'), 'Windows_Server', json('null'))]",`

Comment: But for Linux VMs you still have a `licenseType` property, just with empty value, right?