# Remove property from ARM Template when it's not needed

Tags: azure-rm-template, azure-application-gateway

I'm deploying an application gateway with ARM Template and wants to loop through the creation of listeners.
This is how far I got:

```
"copy": [
                {
                    "name": "httpListeners",
                    "count": "[length(parameters('APPLICATIONS'))]",
                    "input": {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('APPLICATIONS')[copyIndex('httpListeners')].site,'-',parameters('APPLICATIONS')[copyIndex('httpListeners')].protocol,'listener')]",
                        "properties": {
                            "FrontendIPConfiguration": {
                                "Id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayID'), '/frontendIPConfigurations/', variables('frontendIpConfigName'))]"
                            },
                            "FrontendPort": {
                                "Id": "[concat(variables('applicationGatewayID'), '/frontendPorts/', variables('frontendPortName443'))]"
                            },
                            "Protocol": "[parameters('APPLICATIONS')[copyIndex('httpListeners')].protocol]",
                            "SslCertificate": {
                                "Id": "[parameters('APPLICATIONS')[copyIndex('httpListeners')].cert]"
                            },
                            "HostName": "[parameters('APPLICATIONS')[copyIndex('httpListeners')].site]",
                            "RequireServerNameIndication": "[if(equals(parameters('APPLICATIONS')[copyIndex('httpListeners')].protocol, 'HTTPS'), json('true'), json('false'))]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
```

It works well as long as I only create HTTPS listeners, but when I create a HTTP listener I want to get rid of this part:

```
"SslCertificate": {
                            "Id": "[parameters('APPLICATIONS')[copyIndex('httpListeners')].cert]"
                        }
```

Just setting the parameter **parameters('APPLICATIONS')[copyIndex('httpListeners')].cert** to null doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have conditional property in ARM template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53876482/is-it-possible-to-have-conditional-property-in-arm-template) just the other way around

Comment: Not really... His solution ends up with this: `"licenseType": "[if(variables('isWindowsOS'), 'Windows_Server', json('null'))]"` But that doesn't remove the property `licenseType`, it just sets it to null.
I've already tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: @4c74356b41, you helped me out in an other case about subnet and gave me this code to have the opportunity to choose to have a route table associated to subnet or not:
`"routeTable": "[if(equals(parameters('VNET')[copyIndex('Vnets')].Subnets[copyIndex('subnets')].routeTable, json('null')), json('null'), json(concat('{\"id\": \"', resourceId('Microsoft.Network/routeTables', parameters('VNET')[copyIndex('Vnets')].Subnets[copyIndex('subnets')].routeTable), '\"}')))]"`
Not sure though how to transform the code to fit in this case

Comment: how about you look at my answer, not whatever the OP is doing. it talks about your case specifically