# Conditional object construction not working ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to construct an Azure ServiceBus Subscription Rule that will have either a correlation filter or sql filter depending on the length of param's `subjectFilter` array property. I tried this using `if` with `union`, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53880647/15740725). However, it looks like the object is constructed with all properties. For example, the sql filter errors with "At least one system or user property must be set for a correlation filter."

Here's my code (simplified).

- The copy variable contains properties to use for each subscription name and `filterProperties`, with defines a `filterType` and is used as the base `properties` object.
- It also declares a separate object for the `sqlFilterProperties` and `correlationFilterProperties`, respectively.
- Either the `sqlFilterProperties` or `correlationFilterProperties` object should be unioned with the `filterProperties` to construct the complete `properties`.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "resourceName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "topics": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "subscriptionName": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "apiVersion": "2018-01-01-preview",
        "copy": [
            {
                "name": "subscriptions",
                "count": "[length(parameters('topics'))]",
                "input": {
                    "name": "[concat(parameters('resourceName'), '/', parameters('topics')[copyIndex('subscriptions')].name, '/', parameters('subscriptionName'))]",
                    "filterProperties": {
                        "filterType": "[if(greater(length(parameters('topics')[copyIndex('subscriptions')].subjectFilter),1),'sqlFilter','correlationFilter')]"
                    },
                    "sqlFilterProperties": {
                        "sqlFilter": {
                            "sqlExpression": "[concat('sys.subject in (''',join(parameters('topics')[copyIndex('subscriptions')].subjectFilter,''','''), ''')')]",
                            "requiresPreprocessing": false
                        }
                    },
                    "correlationFilterProperties": {
                        "correlationFilter": {
                            "subject": "[parameters('topics')[copyIndex('subscriptions')].subjectFilter[0]]",
                            "requiresPreprocessing": false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/topics/subscriptions/rules",
            "apiVersion": "[variables('apiVersion')]",
            "copy": {
                "name": "subscriptionFilters",
                "count": "[length(parameters('topics'))]"
            },
            "name": "[concat(variables('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].name, '/subject')]",
            "properties": "[union(variables('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].filterProperties, if(startsWith(variables('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].filterProperties.filterType, 'sql'), variables('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].sqlFilterProperties, variables('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].correlationFilterProperties) )]"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this answer from Microsoft through a support ticket. The problem is `subject` metadata property is actually called `label` when creating filters. (In C# it is called `Subject`.) So simply changing the sqlExpression to use `sys.Label` and the correlationFilter properties to use `Label` solved the problem.

See docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messages-payloads

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.message.label?view=azure-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the `union` method directly, you can conditionally assign the filter properties based on the `filter` type. Compare the filter type with `'correlationFilter'` or `'sqlFilter'` using the [`equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-comparison#equals) function.

*You can make the changes listed below to your code and try deployment once again*.

```bash
"correlationFilter":  "[if(equals(variables('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].filterProperties.filterType, 'correlationFilter'), variables('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].correlationFilterProperties.correlationFilter)]",  
"sqlFilter":  "[if(equals(variables('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].filterProperties.filterType, 'sqlFilter'), variables('subscriptions')[copyIndex()].sqlFilterProperties.sqlFilter)]"
```

Alternatively, you can also use system properties like (ContentType, Label, MessageId, ReplyTo) and user-defined values to filter, when you use the `CorrelationRuleFilter` default constructor. Use the `IDictionary string, object`> property Properties to supply user-defined properties for the correlation filter as detailed [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters.md).

Comment: That syntax doesn't work, I get `Unable to evaluate template language function 'if': function requires 3 argument(s) while 2 were provided`. When I pass `json('null')` as the third arg, I get the same errors as when I use `union` in my code.

Comment: Can you refer this [doc](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-invalid-template.md)?

Comment: As mentioned, I resolved the error by passing `json(null)` as the third arg and get the same errors as when I use `union` in my code. IOW putting aside the syntax problem, `if` has same behavior as `union`.